# Setting timeout to slow down the pace of zoom_changed events

Tags: javascript, google-maps, zooming

I have the following code:

```
    google.maps.event.addListener( map, 'dragend', updateBounds );
    google.maps.event.addListener( map, 'zoom_changed', updateBounds );

    function updateBounds() {
      bounds = map.getBounds();
      $.ajax({ url:url, params:{ b:bounds.toUrlValue() } } );
    }
```

so, upon each move/zoom the coords get sent to the server.

The problem is, if the user makes "2-click"-scroll to change the zoom level, 2 events get fired and the server must make double work.

I'd like the client to "forget" the 1st zoom-event and send only the last one.

How to do that?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do just what your title suggests...set a timeout on every zoom event, then clear it and reset it if there's another zoom event before the timeout completes, perhaps like so:

```
google.maps.event.addListener( map, 'dragend', updateBounds );
google.maps.event.addListener( map, 'zoom_changed', updateDebounce );

var debounceTimeout;
function updateDebounce() {
     window.clearTimeout(debounceTimeout);
     debounceTimeout = window.setTimeout(updateBounds, 1000);
}

function updateBounds() {
  bounds = map.getBounds();
  $.ajax({ url:url, params:{ b:bounds.toUrlValue() } } );
}
```